# Is a professor allowed to require me to give him permission to speak with my doctor before letting me make up an exam?

Tags: united-states, health, privacy

I study in the USA.

Can a professor ask me to waive my right to privacy so he can talk to my doctor about my medical condition? He says he needs that in order to allow me to take a make-up midterm for an exam that I missed, even though a medical note certifying my illness is provided.

Also, the doctor that gave the note is usually a nurse practitioner (NP), but he instead wants a note from a doctor of medicine (MD).

Comment: What does the existing note actually say? At some institutions, it's not enough to provide a note that you went to a health care professional; it has to specifically state that you were diagnosed with something that prevented you taking the exam (and some schools also specify what kinds of medical officials can make that judgment).

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77960/discussion-on-question-by-bigboyb-can-a-professor-ask-me-to-waive-my-right-to-pr). Please see the above notice.

Comment: A general comment: if someone is insisting that you should give them permission to do something, then no, they are not allowed to require you to give permission.

Comment: @Kat The OP shouldn't need to be concerned with any specific authority.  If *any* authority has a rule for this, it's relevant and worth learning about.  Vagueness and generality aren't always bad.

Answer (score 97):

That sounds like a big no to me, but that comes from Germany with very strict rules on privacy. Your medical condition is your thing, and yours alone. If you have a document that certifies your illnesss, that should be enough.

Check your university policies, what you need to provide in case off illness HAS to be written down somewhere. If it states there that a written thing is enough, it is enough. Point your professor to that document, if that does not help talk to faculty cousellors. They should be able to help you.

Comment: I would go one step further and *definitely* talk to the faculty counsellor about this. By asking alone the professor may be overstepping his boundaries far enough that officials should at least be aware of it.

Comment: Take care how you handle this, while the situation can get you a replacement exam - the professor could have the choice WHEN it will take place ie next week or next semester...

Comment: I am from Germany, too, and I recently read that some medical faculties require you to give detailed information about your illness to the exam committee so that they can decide whether you were "ill enough" to not take the exam.

Comment: Two German sources, I do not know if the details are correct: http://www.spiegel.de/lebenundlernen/uni/attest-reicht-nicht-studenten-sollen-mediziner-von-schweigepflicht-entbinden-a-1094325.html
and 
https://www.zeit.de/campus/2010/02/studieren-dwdd

Comment: @J.FabianMeier The sources already tell you that data protection officers pushed back hard against this, the second source even openly throws the question of compliance with the basic law into the room. Those articles are furthermore years old, and I have not seen such ridiculous request in recent times, so I'd guess this has been squashed, hard.

Comment: _Check your university policies, what you need to provide in case off illness HAS to be written down somewhere_ - I don't know about Germany, but this is not true in the US.  At my university, in cases of illness the rules just say it is up to the discretion of the instructor.  (And the practice is usually to ask for a doctor's note.)

Comment: @Kimball You’re safe to assume that in Germany, there are door-stopper leaflets with all eventualities explained if you should be sick, what actions should be taken and so on (I am German). Do you mean “not true in general in the U.S.”, “not true in this one university”, or “not true for most universities”? That would be both interesting to know and a pretty good answer.

Comment: @Kimball In Gemany, everything that should reasonably have established procedures be written down *will* be written down. Either in law or in policy. We don't like eventualities. getting sick is commonplace enough that it warrants procedure.

Comment: @Narusan I mean at least "not true in general in the US."  I imagine my university's policy is similar to many public US universities, but I'm not positive.  I couldn't tell if this answer was asserting that statement should be true outside of Germany or not, so I just wanted to point out it's not true everywhere.

Comment: This answer is wrong as it stands. The professor may absolutely ask nearly anything  they want legally.

Comment: @tuskiomi: even in the sources J.FabianMeier linked, it is not the professor who can ask but the exam committee. (And, as I understand, those questions [of which I'm not sure how legal they are - see the cited legal opinions of data/privacy protection officers] are not about waiving all rights to privacy, but certain possibly rather specific ones. Such as specifying that the medical attesttation must say that the illness is not related to the fact that there is this specific exam at hand.)

Comment: @SolarMike I'm almost certain this is not true in the US. Surely the replacement exam would need to take place during the normal semester.

Comment: @sgroves If the semester's over, there may be no choice. I have heard of universities where you can only retake finals during the next finals week (three months later).

Comment: I highly doubt the correctness of the answer .To my understanding a slip of someone like a nurse partitioner (-> not  a doctor of medicine), is worth nothing in this regard in germany. He might not be allowed to ask about the sickness itself but asking that the note will be written by a doctor is the only way also in germany as far as I know.

Comment: @KamiKaze The OP is in the US, where an NP's signature should be perfectly sufficient.

Comment: @Kimball My school prefers you talk to the instructor but otherwise leaves it up to a separate office (e.d. advising or disability). A decent number random schools do as well, such as Duke, UAlbany, Harvard, RPI, Cornell, and GA Tech which even specifically says "Students have the right to expect that their privacy will be protected under HIPAA..."

Comment: @AzorAhai This answer made from a german view point and in this regard wrong.

Comment: @KamiKaze Where in this answer do you get something coming from a nurse? It simply says "document certifying" - presumably, that document comes from someone recognized by the university.

Comment: @corsiKa The question specifies that the note the OP has is signed by an NP, not an MD.

Answer (score 47):

I am not sure if it is relevant to your situation since you haven't mentioned a country (I am in the UK), however I have personally been asked a similar thing when the professor wanted to check that the medical note provided was indeed from my doctor and relevant to the allowances being made for me.

The privacy I was giving up by letting him talk about my condition was not for them to fully discuss the details of my illness, but instead to merely check that the note was real, that my illness did indeed prevent me from being able to take an exam. This was standard uni procedure, so should be documented for you to check if its something similar.

If you have data protection laws similar to the UK in your country then the doctor cannot even confirm that you exist to a 3rd party until you give them permission to discuss with that specific 3rd party, and if that is the case then it is perfectly reasonable for the university to request you give the doctors office permission to disclose that you are a patient, and that the letter is genuine.

Equally it is perfectly acceptable for you to only give the doctor's permission to give that specific information (and withhold any additional information) as it is your data, and they would be bound by the permissions you give them.

On the other hand if the university are asking for complete access that is a no go, but I think if you communicate more with the lecturer about what they actually want, it won't be as bad as giving them full access and details.

Answer (score 33):

At my university (a well-off private university in the USA), there is an Office of Disability Services who, in situations like this, acts as the middle-man between doctors and professors to determine test accommodations.  You fill out an accommodation application, your doctor fills out a form that this office supplies, you submit both to the office, then they meet with you and determine reasonable accommodation.  The professor is then informed by this office what the accommodations are and is required to abide by them.

I bring this up so that you can check whether your university has a similar office or service.  It's good in that the revelation of private medical information is contained only to a single office specifically designed to handle such information appropriately, and professors and other university members need not know the information, just the required accommodations.

If your university does not have such a service, then I don't know what to do, but I'd imagine (as others have pointed out) that there must exists some policy of what is an appropriate level of proof of necessity of medical accommodation, and if what your professor is asking exceeds that, then point them to the policy.

Comment: I would be shocked to learn of ANY college or university in the USA that does not have an office like this.

Comment: This does not seem like a request for a disability-related test accommodation.  At my school, this office would not get involved in this matter.

Comment: @ScottSeidman, at my school medical accommodations (even temporary ones) are handled by the disability office.

Comment: @ScottSeidman My school (US) handles temporary things such as this.

Comment: @ScottSeidman My school (US, private engineering school) has a vaguely named "Office of Undergraduate Education" which deals with things like this. I also googled a number of universities and I have not been able to find one without a similar policy, in fact most of them prohibit instructors from lowering grades due to absences which are approved by whatever office handles them.

Answer (score 27):

It is highly unethical for the professor to make this request.  The professor is asking for the student to waive their right to medical privacy and in exchange all the professor will do is their job.

The professor has the right to contact the student's NP to confirm the information on the note and discuss whether student had a bona fide reason to miss the midterm. (I have done this.) However the nature of that reason is none of their business.

Whether and NP is good enough or an MD is required should be set out in the university's policies.  If the university doesn't have a policy, then the department may. If the department doesn't, the policy should be on the information provided by the instructor.  If there is no policy, then an NP should be as good as an MD, since making this sort of assessment is within the normal scope of practice for NPs (in most jurisdictions).

That said, the best advice for the student is to find out what their university's policies are on medical notes.

(I'm working in Canada.  This would be the situation in Canada and I expect also in the U.S. and Europe.  Other places could have other norms.)

Comment: Agree completely!  You should be able to contact the medical provider to confirm the veracity of the claim, but not to get any information about the nature of the condition (other than that it would prevent the student from taking the exam).  I have had a large number of students lately (4 or 5 a semester) bringing in notes from online doctors.  This has been particularly frustrating to verify, and I suspect these docs are basically in the business of forging medical excuses.  However, I cannot ever figure out how to actually contact the doctor.

Comment: @StevenGubkin: over here (Germany) the doctor in question would not be allowed to tell the professor whether the student is their patient unless the student waived their privacy rights to that question. OTOH, sick certificates here are on official forms, so this question doesn't arise. And, if there's a suspicion that the certificate is a favor, you could ask the student to bring a certificate by the so-called Amtsarzt who is a doctor and public official at the local health authority.

Comment: @cbeleites in the US (and it seems like Canada is similar) really all we do is check the authenticity of the note.  Sometimes offices (sadly) just start running off photocopies of the medical excuse forms and so even a real form can look incredibly fake.

Comment: Are you saying you called the doctor's office and asked if Jane Doe was a patient there? And they confirmed? That seems very unethical on the office's part.

Comment: @cbeleites: Isn't there a _Hochschularzt_ who could provide something similar? I know my institution had one.

Comment: @AzorAhai If the student submitted a note, he or she has *already* alleged that they are a patient there; the doctor's office should be able to confirm whether the note is authentic (in which case they haven't added any new info to what the student already disclosed) or not (in which case there isn't any doctor-patient relationship, so no doctor-patient confidentiality to be breached).

Comment: @aeismail: I've never heard of a Hochschularzt (≈ university doctor). Closest thing that comes to my mind is Betriebsarzt, but they're for work-related prevention questions (in general, not only at universities). I've never heard of them for questions of sick leave or student sick leave certificates for missing an exam. That was always either immediately Amtsarzt or first normal MD, and the exam office/committee reserved the right to demand an attestation by the Amtsarzt in cases of repeated sickness at exams or for very important exams (state exam).

Comment: I would argue that it's more than highly unethical: it's extremely immoral too. One might argue they're one and the same but I see there as being a difference (albeit perhaps subtly so). They should be ashamed of themselves. And I imagine they'd love the positions reversed...

Comment: @AzorAhai What I have done is to phone the doctor and asked her to confirm that it was her medical opinion that the student was unable to attend my midterm.  I did this because the letter was not all that clear on that point.  I don't think that was unethical on her part because she only divulged information that her patient had requested her to divulge.  I don't think it was unethical on my part because I was trying to establish whether the letter was sufficient to allow the student to miss the midterm. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @aeismail Universities in North America (or at least Canada) generally have a clinic on campus. However students are free to choose their own Doctor (or NP in some places) and do not have to use the university cliinic.

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell Also in the US. And usually students use it because it is much cheaper and many services are included in students' fees.

Answer (score 17):

As someone who has both been an undergraduate student and, oddly, served as Instructor of Record for a college-level undergraduate course, in the US:

- it is completely reasonable for him to ask you for a doctor's note, and it is not too unreasonable to stipulate that the note come from a professional physician (MD, DO, DDS, etc.) and/or bear the letterhead of the clinic, etc. Use your judgement.
- By [HIPAA](https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-individuals/guidance-materials-for-consumers/index.html), your healthcare provider can't discuss anything about your treatment with others without your consent (barring a few exceptional cases). By FERPA, your professor can't discuss anything related to your education with others without your consent. So, neither of them can contact each other about you without your consent; a conversation between them would be even more off limits.
- Give him a note signed by a MD and w/ the clinic's letterhead. This should be authoritative enough for every reasonable person. If he insists, say NO immediately.
- Again, if he insists, he is treating you unfairly. Escalate the issue immediately. Especially, contact the following people, as you see fit:

  1. the department chair;
  2. your academic advisor (if this position exists at your school);
  3. your advising dean (if this office exists at your school);
  4. the Dean of Student Affairs (or equivalent), and/or his associates;
  5. your school's associate dean for undergraduate education, and, if the situation gets really bad, your school's dean.

I would not contact HR, though, as it is not their issue. This is an academic/instructional issue involving the mistreatment of a student by an instructor.

Comment: The student should check the allowed regulations carefully. While HIPAA and FERPA do not allow communication between doctor and instructor (unless privacy is waived by the student), policy dictates what the student can expect. For example, at my school, missing an exam or class for anything that isn't a university-sanctioned activity is entirely up to instructors' discretions. They can simply say "no" and give a zero, if they choose.

Comment: _Again, if he insists, he is treating you unfairly._ - I'm not so sure.  I've been in situations (particularly when the student is asking to take an exam weeks later) where I've wanted more information than a note saying a student had a medical appointment or was excused from school just for the day of the exam.  I haven't done this, and I wouldn't want medical details, just to know that the student has a valid medical excuse for the whole situation, but have thought about it.  (Just like aeismail, what to do is left up to the discretion of the instructor at my university.)

Comment: @Kimball Yep, but I still believe that insisting to talk to a healthcare provider is off-limits. That is why doctor's notes exist in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

As with any privacy matter, the one ultimately making a decision is **you**.
A professor is allowed to ask for you to waive your rights to privacy so your medical discussion can be discussed with the doctor, but you have the choice to agree or say no.

So, a professor can most definitely ask if it would ease communication with the doctor and evaluation of a re-take exam. Nothing wrong with that request and the comments I've read so far on this question are a little on the strong side. No need to jump on the professor's case just for asking.

Where the line is drawn here is if your refusal to waive your right to privacy has a direct impact on your exam or result from it. In *that* case, taking this to HR or the uni board would be a good thing, because that would not be proper.

Comment: I have had to deal with fake doctor’s notes : sent the suspect note to the doc who said it was fake ... date changed etc And, the doc was kind, he could have prosecuted the student as that is a serious act...

Comment: I disagree.  Protecting students' privacy is important.  Beyond checking the genuineness of the certificate, the professor has no business talking to the doctor.

Comment: To HR? How is HR involved in this?

Comment: @AzorAhai: The first step should be to appeal this decision and behavior to the chair of the department. Going to the board will take much longer. The HR department—or its equivalent in the administration (the provost's office in the US) could get involved if there   is a faculty conduct issue.

Comment: Your assertion that a professor even *can* ask is not obviously true, and almost certainly false. The act of even asking a student to do this is a serious transgression.

Comment: I find these comments rather riduculous. Have you all fallen so far from normal human interaction that simply asking is already considered a major offense? Like I stated very clearly it must be an open question with no repercussions if refused. But the question itself is most certainly not something that should be punished or marked negatively.

Comment: Asking someone to forfeit their privacy when you are in a position of power over them is deplorable and deeply unethical - should be a first time firing offense for any university official. The power imbalance between student and professor is big enough that any question to that effect carries an "or else" like "or else you'll get a zero on the exam". No, just no.

Answer (score 3):

One thing the professor can do, without violating medical privacy laws, is to simply contact the medical practice to ask if they can speak to Doctor Such-And-Such (in other words, verify that the doctor is, actually, doctor), and then to ask Doctor Such-And-Such to verify that he/she was indeed the author of the note. After all, the doctor sent the note. So you could say to the doctor "While I do not wish you to talk to my doctor about my medical condition, feel free to talk to my doctor to verify that the note is valid".

Answer (score 0):

You ask about what's *allowed*, which may not be the same as what's *right* or *ethical*.  In the absence of some course and/or university policy (and/or state law) stating otherwise, the decision of whether or not to allow a student to retake a missed exam is entirely at the professor's discretion.

As a first step, you should check to see whether any such policy exists at your school or for your course.  If one does, then you're in luck.  Refer your professor to it.  If they still don't come around, involve an advisor, department head, or similar third-party to resolve the duspute.

If there is no such policy, you'll need to shift your perspective a bit.

The default scenario at this point is that you've failed the midterm.  That's the outcome you have if the professor simply sits there and does nothing.

So while it's true that the professor cannot legally require or otherwise compel you to waive doctor-patient confidentiality, it may also be true (barring any university policies in your favor) that you cannot require or compel the professor to let you retake the midterm.  They can deny your request for any reason, or for none at all.

You've got a stalemate; the professor is almost certainly allowed to *ask* you to waive doctor-patient confidentiality, and you're certainly allowed to refuse.  In which case the stalemate continues, and you're stuck with the default outcome of a failed midterm.

In essence, nobody is requiring anything.  You missed an exam, and you want to be allowed to retake it.  You may have a completely valid and reasonable excuse for missing the exam, but in the absence of any policy to the contrary whether or not you get to an exam is at the professor's sole discretion.  *You're asking the professor for a favor, and they're asking one back*.

None of which means that the professor has been reasonable or fair or ethical if they've not accepted a genuine medical excuse at face value, or that the incident couldn't have negative repercussions for the professor if the details get out, or that you wouldn't find support if you took the matter higher up in the university food-chain.

But your question is about what the professor can do.  And they *can* ask you to let them speak to your doctor, yes.  They can't force you to, but they *can* sit on their hands and do nothing if you refuse.  They *shouldn't* do that sort of thing, but without a university policy stating otherwise they almost certainly can.

Answer (score -1):

The answer will greatly depends on your region.

Some things to consider would be to **look at your local laws** and your **University's guidelines**, too.

A note from and MD rather than an NP may be a valid request depending on your University's guidelines. Many universities require a note specifically from an MD for such occasions.

As for his asking to talk to your doctor, it would be useful to know what he is trying to achieve that a note couldn't do. Ask him why exactly he needs to speak to your doctor.

If he doubts that you have/had an illness then it should be completely unnecessary to ask for more than a note from an MD. If that's all he wants to do and doesn't back down after getting a note, look at your local laws and University's guidelines and contact HR if he oversteps any of those.

But you didn't mention what your illness was, perhaps he may not be doubting that you have the illness but rather wants to assess whether or not it was a good reason to defer an exam. If his questions are about the illness in general and why it would be a valid reason to miss an exam, **suggest consulting any doctor about it.**

Lastly, and perhaps the least popular suggestion, ask yourself exactly what you'll lose by letting your professor know about your illness. Perhaps the easiest solution, albeit least favorable, is to just let him speak to your doctor about it. His demands may be out of line, but if you were honest about your illness there's no *real harm* to you for allowing him to speak to your doctor about it.

Comment: Well, if the OP was recovering from an abortion, or from syphilis, then they might not want the Prof knowing.  It's also important that people get sniffy about their medical privacy when they have had a cold - precisely in order to protect those whose condition was more embarressing.

Comment: I understand the humiliation aspect of things, hence why I mentioned the possibility of just letting the prof know as my last point. Regarding syphilis or an abortion as examples you pointed out, letting the prof know about your condition won't GET you syphilis or force you into a situation where you get an abortion - that's what I meant by no *real harm*. If it boils down to failing a class or allowing your professor to talk to your doctor, it's something that should be considered.

Comment: You’re assuming that a violation of privacy is not “real harm”. The existence of privacy laws suggests otherwise.

Comment: since, at the time of writing my answer, the OP's location was not specified, there was a possibility in which the professor's requirements were legal and allowed by the University. In that situation, it is a very reasonable suggestion to ask OP to assess exactly how much harm they receive by obliging to those demands. I clearly mentioned that I understood the humiliation aspect of privacy laws, and by *real harm* I clearly meant physical harm; allowing your professor to know about your condition won't make your condition worse than it already is.

Answer (score -4):

Since this sounds like a disability, talk to your college/university's disability office. Get an accommodation letter that allows you to make up classes and exams. In every college I have attended, this letter is sufficient for establishing that you have a disability and the professor would be violating university policies if he were to require more information on the medical condition.

Comment: This does not sound like a disability.